# How to determining if other processes are using a file descriptor?

Tags: c++, sockets, file-descriptor

I'm writing an application in C++ for a linux environment which will operate in a multi-process setup (i.e. the program calls fork()).  As part of the application I am creating some file descriptors (sockets in this case), I am wondering if it is possible for the program to determine how many other processes have that file descriptor open.  In this case I want to perform special actions before closing the last copy of the file descriptor.

I know that the implementation of close for file descriptors like TCP sockets seem to accomplish this but I'm not sure how.

**Edit:** I'm looking for a way to accomplish this without access to the main or fork code. The code is in a library providing these sockets to other applications.

Example code:

```
void handle_socket(int socket_fd) {
    // determine number of processes with this socket_fd open.
    if (num_proc == 1) {
        // Special code
    }
    close(socket_fd);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int socket_fd = socket(...);
    if (fork() == 0) {
        //action 1
    } else {
       // action 2
    }
    handle_socket(socket_fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how about using semaphores and/or a shared memory location to keep track number of open file descriptors?

Comment: Might work, but it would rely on being able to add code to any fork call, to execute the counting code. My example shows having access to the code but that may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing the main() that spawns the child processes, you should be waiting for those children to finish.